# Mi consola de eclipse no muestra tildes

Tags: java, consola

Acabo de instalar mi eclipse junto con el jdk-20 de java pero a la hora de mandar por consola unas simples líneas me salen unos cuadros blancos omitiendo las tildes de las vocales, ¿alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba esto. Puede ser que no tengas las preferencias configuradas: En el IDE Eclipse, en su pantalla principal, ir a Window > Preferences.

 En la ventana Preferences, vete a la lista de la izquierda y seleccionar General > Content Types. En el panel derecho, se presentará una lista conteniendo una serie de tipos de archivos. Busca el tipo de archivo que desea corregir su visualización ( Text > Java Source Files).

 En el panel inferior, debajo de la lista de extensiones de archivos, aparece un campo con la etiqueta Default Encoding. Coloca el valor ISO-8859-1 y actualiza

Answer (score 1):

es normal que la consola en eclipse no lo muestra como algunos caracteres de puntuación como mi persona, pero se puede cambiar por medio de la configuración propia de eclipse envió link de que me ayudo en la configuración de acentos entre otros https://blog.buhoos.com/eclipse-configuracion-para-aceptar-caracteres-especiales-n-acentos-etc/